# Javascript - cloned element not responding to click

Tags: javascript, object, event-handling, clone, element

I have a problem when I have cloned an element, that element doesn't respond to onclick. I want to remove the class 'selected' for that element and other cloned element. I can still add and remove that class on the original element but not the cloned one. When you press 't' you clone the selected object(s). Them in turn should be selected and unselected on mouseclick.

I know there are some similar questions out there but they all use jquery which I'm not interested in of helped by.

I have a fiddle with the whole code here: http://jsfiddle.net/oveht2zr/

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Sandbox</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
    </head>

    <body id="content">
        <h1>My Sandbox</h1>

        <div id="box1" class="box">
        </div>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Affected JS:

```
let myContent = document.querySelector('#content');
let box = document.querySelector('.box');

let z = 2;

function cloneSelected() {
    let all = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
    let i;

    for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        let clone = all[i].cloneNode(true);
        clone.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * browserHeight) + 'px';
        clone.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * browserWidth) + 'px';
        clone.setAttribute('id', 'box' + z);
        clone.style.zIndex = z;
        myContent.appendChild(clone);
        z++;            
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    let key = event.key;

    switch(key) {
        case 'e':
            circle();
            break;
        case 'q':
            resizeUp();
            break;
        case 'w':
            resizeDown();
            break;
        case 'r':
            changeColor();
            break;
        case 't':
            cloneSelected();
            break;
    }

    box.style.top = (browserHeight / 2) - (boxHeight / 2) + 'px';
    box.style.left = (browserWidth / 2) - (boxWidth / 2) + 'px';
});
```

Regards

Comment: Reaading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode): "_[cloneNode] does not copy event listeners added using addEventListener()_"

Comment: I see no onclick event listener being added

Comment: I'm guessing the event listener is not getting attached to the cloned element. If you were using jquery, you would take advantage of event delegation, which would attach the listener to newly created objects even after the listener was initialized. What about removing all listeners upon clone (so as to not have duplicate listeners on pre-existing elements), and then adding them to all elements immediately after?

Comment: @LexJacobs You can delegate events using vanilla JS as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cloneSelected function you should subscribe the clone to the click

```
function cloneSelected() {
    let all = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
    let i;

    for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        let clone = all[i].cloneNode(true);
        clone.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * browserHeight) + 'px';
        clone.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * browserWidth) + 'px';
        clone.setAttribute('id', 'box' + z);
        clone.style.zIndex = z;
        clone.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            if (clone.classList.contains('selected')) {
                event.target.classList.remove('selected');
            } else {
                event.target.classList.add('selected');
            }})
        myContent.appendChild(clone);
        z++;            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your `eventListener` to a variable called `box`, which you set at the top of your function. At the time you set this variable, your cloned box does not exist, so it is not included in the `querySelectorAll` that creates the `box` variable, and is therefore not getting the `eventListener`.

I haven't examined your code in great detail, but I would imagine you could simply re-set `box` in the `cloneSelected` function after your `myContent.appendChild`.